# Is there an example X-Windows application that dumps all X server information?

Tags: unix, x11

I'm dealing with X application behaviors sometimes changing depending on the remote X server (particularly Windows-based ones like eXceed, Xming, FastX, and Cygwin-X). Is there any "simple" way to determine what the remote X server is?

Comment: xdpyinfo? https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xdpyinfo.1.xhtml

Comment: @AndreySidorov I think this may be exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try it.